# Is there a way to get events from all users calendars (default and others) in one call in office 365 API.

Tags: office365, office365api

In office 365 API, i didn't find any single service which returns all events from users calendars in one call. 
If user has 3 calendars, then need to make three calls by passing calendar Id.

First need to get Calendar Ids by calling

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/calendars
```

Then for each Calendar Id, need to get events by calling

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/{version}/me/calendars/{calendar_id}/calendarview?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}
```

If there is any single call then it will be reduce the round trips.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a single call to get a "merged" view of all the calendars. It's an interesting idea, I think you should post it on [UserVoice](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131775-outlook-apis).

Comment: ok, Thank you again Jason for your quick answer. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Its true that we cannot hit multiple calendars in one hit, however we can use parallel foreach to make simultaneous calls to get faster response.

```
Task[] CalendarListEvents = new Task[CalendarList.Count];
Parallel.ForEach(CalendarList, (Calendar) =>
{ 
    tasksToFetchDailyEvents[index] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {               
              // Code to fetch Events and add to list
    });

});
Task.WaitAll(CalendarListEvents);
```